# Facebook api - using more than one api by using php SDK did make the application run slow?

Tags: php, facebook

Iam developing a php facebook application that will display the facebook score of the facebook user depends on the count of friends, videos, subscribires, uploaded photos, his/her status comments, liked pages and links.
As you know we haveto take this data from different api url so, i wrote a php code like this

```
 if($user){

   try {
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        echo "err0";
        $user = null;
      }

      try{
        $user_freinds = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        echo "err1";
        $user = null;
      }

        try{
            $user_subscribers = $facebook->api('/me/subscribers');
            } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        echo "err2";
        $user = null;
      }

        try{ 
        $user_links = $facebook->api('/me/links');
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        echo "err3";
        $user = null;
      }

        try{
            $user_foto = $facebook->api('/me/albums');
            } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        echo "err4";
        $user = null;
      }
        try{
        $user_likes = $facebook->api('/me/likes');
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        echo "err5";
        $user = null;
      }
        try{
        $user_videos = $facebook->api('/me/videos/uploaded');
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        echo "err6";
        $user = null;
      }
        try{
        $user_statues = $facebook->api('/me/statuses');
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        echo "err7";
        $user = null;
      }

   }
```

but unfortunatley this made my application working more slow , there is any recommendation from you to make it run more quick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the API many times in a row. This might take a while and you certainly are not able to speed up the calls. Here are a few tips for you:

- Only request all infos on the first time a user enters your app and show a loading icon or something similar to let him know somethings going on
- **Cache the data** you obtained from Facebook and use cached version instead of querying API on every page/visit
- Use [Batch Requests](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/) to *"access significant amounts of data in a single go"*
- [Optimize the Graph API data fetch using ETags](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/627/)
- Use the [Real Time Updates](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/) feature
- And/Or: let the user decide which data should be requested